# How to find sum of multiple columns in a table in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table `Emp` which has these rows:

```
Emp_cd | Val1  | Val2  | Val3  | Total
-------+-------+-------+-------+-------
 1     | 1.23  | 2.23  | 3.43  | 
 2     | 23.03 | 12.23 | 2.92  |
 3     | 7.23  | 9.05  | 13.43 |
 4     | 03.21 | 78.23 | 9.43  |
```

I want to find `SUM` of `Val1, Val2, Val3` and which will show in the `Total` column.

Comment: You can also have Total as Computed Column.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Easy:

```
SELECT 
   Val1,
   Val2,
   Val3,
   (Val1 + Val2 + Val3) as 'Total'
FROM Emp
```

or if you just want one row:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(Val1) as 'Val1',
   SUM(Val2) as 'Val2',
   SUM(Val3) as 'Val3',
   (SUM(Val1) + SUM(Val2) + SUM(Val3)) as 'Total'
FROM Emp
```

Comment: Beware that the sum of the first query will be NULL if on of the Val is NULL.

Comment: In the second query too, if `Valx` is null for all rows, this query will break.

Comment: a simple solution for the null problem is to add an isnull function - SUM(isnull(val1,0)) as 'Val1'

Comment: @aF how about dynamic columns?

Comment: `NVL(value, default value)` can be used in hive instead of `ISNULL`

Answer (score 49):

You must also be aware of `null` records:

```
SELECT  (ISNULL(Val1,0) + ISNULL(Val2,0) + ISNULL(Val3,0)) as 'Total'
FROM Emp
```

Usage of `ISNULL`:

```
ISNULL(col_Name, replace value)
```

Comment: If you are working with `mysql` then you need to use `IFNULL()`

Answer (score 30):

Just as a regular `SELECT`?

```
SELECT 
   Val1, Val2, Val3,
   Total = Val1 + Val2 + Val3
FROM dbo.Emp
```

Or do you want to determine that total and update the table with those values?

```
UPDATE dbo.Emp
SET Total = Val1 + Val2 + Val3
```

If you want to have this total be current at all times - you should have a computed column in your table:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Emp
ADD CurrentTotal AS Val1 + Val2 + Val3 PERSISTED
```

Then you will *always* get the current total - even if the values change:

```
SELECT 
   Val1, Val2, Val3, CurrentTotal
FROM dbo.Emp
```

Comment: Even this one is also working fine but I cant mark your answer as only one we can mark as answer... Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select sum(num_tax_amount+num_total_amount) from table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example using COALESCE. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

```
SELECT (COALESCE(SUM(val1),0) + COALESCE(SUM(val2), 0)
+ COALESCE(SUM(val3), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(val4), 0)) AS 'TOTAL'
FROM Emp
```

Comment: The question asks for a entry per row, not just a single grand total.

Comment: The question is: How to find sum of multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, but it means sum as in the mathematical term to add things. Not as in getting an aggregate row.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use a simple query,

```
select emp_cd, val1, val2, val3,
(val1+val2+val3) as total 
from emp;
```

In case you need to insert a new row,

```
insert into emp select emp_cd, val1, val2, val3,
(val1+val2+val3) as total 
from emp;
```

In order to update,

```
update emp set total = val1+val2+val3;
```

This will update for all comumns

Comment: But if the value of any one of val1, val2, val3 is null then Total will be null, so either add AND condition or Use ISNULL(column_name, replace_value)

Answer (score 0):

Needed to do similar work on a Postgres db table with null value. Ended up creating a function as there are too `COALESCE` to add.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION array_sum_float(float[])
    RETURNS float
AS
$$
DECLARE
    arrInts ALIAS FOR $1;
    sum int DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN
    FOR I IN ARRAY_LOWER(arrInts, 1)..ARRAY_UPPER(arrInts, 1)
        LOOP
            sum = sum + COALESCE(arrInts[I], 0);
        END LOOP;
    RETURN sum;
END;
$$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT array_sum_float(ARRAY [6,8, null, 2]);
SELECT array_sum_float(ARRAY [Val1, Val2, Val3]) from Emp;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Emp_cd, Val1, Val2, Val3, SUM(Val1 + Val2 + Val3) AS TOTAL 
FROM Emp
GROUP BY Emp_cd, Val1, Val2, Val3
```

Comment: Why you need to add `Group By` And `SUM`?, You just change one of the answers by making it slower! ;).

Answer (score -3):

use a trigges it will work:-

**->CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name BEFORE INSERT ON table_name**

**FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.column_name3 = NEW.column_name1 + NEW.column_name2;**

this will only work only when you will **insert a row** in table not when you will be updating your table for such a pupose 
create another trigger of different name and use **UPDATE** on the place of **INSERT** in the above syntax