# How to get total time in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 columns of datatype `time`.

How to get total time for each one by using SQL query?

I tried the following I get result format 90, 30, 120 minute I want result to be HH:mm

```
01:30, 00:30, 02:00
```

Code:

```
SELECT 
    EmpNum, 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', EarlyOT)),
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', late)), 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', [ExcessOT])) 
FROM 
    TblAttendReports 
WHERE
    EmpNum = 11983
GROUP BY 
    EmpNum
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find sum of multiple columns in a table in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033340/how-to-find-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-a-table-in-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to re-format your output. Here is an idea:

```
;WITH TimesCte as
(
    SELECT 
        EmpNum, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', EarlyOT)) ear_min,
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', late)) lat_min, 
        SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:00:00', [ExcessOT])) exc_min 
    FROM 
        TblAttendReports 
    WHERE
        EmpNum = 11983
    GROUP BY 
        EmpNum
)
SELECT  EmpNum,
        ,RTRIM(ear_min/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(ear_min%60),2)
        ,RTRIM(lat_min/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(lat_min%60),2)
        ,RTRIM(exc_min/60) + ':' + RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(exc_min%60),2)
  FROM TimesCte;
```