# Sum across rows in sql table

Tags: sql

I am relatively new to sql, so this may be an easy one. I have a table that keeps track of individual numbers for people everyday. It looks something like this;

```
person1 | person2 | person3 | Date
__________________________________
2       | 4       | 5       | 12/2/2015
__________________________________
3       |  5      |  6      | 12/1/2015
```

What I would like to do is add another column that lists the total completed everyday. Something like this:

```
person1 | person2 | person3 | Date       | Total completed
___________________________________________________________
2       | 4       | 5       | 12/2/2015  | 11
___________________________________________________________
3       |  5      |  6      | 12/1/2015  | 14
```

I know how to use `SUM()` on columns, but it doesn't seem to work on rows. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033340/how-to-find-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-a-table-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2):

Add another column in the table as `Total_completed` and do an update statement as below

```
update your_table
set total_completed = person1+person2+person3
```

But if you are looking to select the same without adding a new column to the table, you can simply do a select statement as below

```
select person1,person2,person3,[date],person1+person2+person3 as total from 
your_table
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the question you're asking highlights a deeper issue about table and database design, specifically relating to the concept of normalization.

What happens if the number of people completing a task on a day changes? If only one or two people completing tasks, you can get by with only filling out some of the columns, but what happens if you have more than three people? Adding additional columns means that any query that accesses that table needs to be rewritten to utilize the new columns, and the table entries with three or fewer entries need to be updated to populate the new columns with values (or appropriately handle NULLs)

I would suggest a table structure that looks more like the following:

```
table PEOPLE:
personID integer, 
(...other information about the person)

table PEOPLE_TASKS_COMPLETED:
personID integer, (this will point at a row in the PEOPLE table)
tasksCompleted integer,
dateCompleted date
```

Breaking down your data in this way allows you to find the total number of tasks completed by *any* number of people on a specific date, using a query like the following:

```
select dateCompleted, SUM(tasksCompleted)
from PEOPLE_TASKS_COMPLETED
GROUP BY dateCompleted
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume you person1, person2, person3 columns are same data type(INT?), following query should do it.

```
SELECT person1, person2, person3, Date, person1+person2+person3 as TotalCompleted
FROM yourtable
```