# How to get the sum of a column in while looping?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, sum

I have a table using while MySQLi fetch array:

| C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $vsc1 | $vsc2 | $vsc3 | $vsc4 | $totalvsc // 6.662 |
| $vsc1 | $vsc2 | $vsc3 | $vsc4 | $totalvsc // 6.916 |
| $vsc1 | $vsc2 | $vsc3 | $vsc4 | $totalvsc // 7.15 |
| $vsc1 | $vsc2 | $vsc3 | $vsc4 | $totalvsc // 6.107 |
| -- | -- | -- | Total Vektor S | sum of $totalvsc ($totvs) // 6.66213.57820.72826.835 |

I want to get sum of $totalvsc from every row ($totvs)

The result of the code is 6.66213.57820.72826.835.
The result should not be this, but 26.835.

I've tried, but it doesn't work. Here's the code:

```
<tr>
   <th colspan="7">Total Vektor S</th>
      <td>
         <?php
            $totvs = 0;
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_alternatif");
            while ($hasil1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
            {
               $vsc1 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[2],$nb1),3);
               $vsc2 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[3],-$nb2),3);
               $vsc3 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[4],$nb3),3);
               $vsc4 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[5],-$nb4),3);
               $totalvs = $vsc1 + $vsc2 + $vsc3 + $vsc4;
               $totvs += $totalvs;
               echo $totvs; 
            }
       ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone can help me?

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what outcome do you get?

Comment: outcome is " 6.66213.57820.72826.835 "

Comment: number_format returns string. Use it only to display

Comment: means $vsc1,$vsc2,$vsc3,$vsc4 not using number_format ?

Comment: You need use type. Like @splash58 say, `number_format` return string, so you need to to use float type for adding.

Comment: You probably want to put the `echo` outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: You say the wrong output is 6.66213.57820.728**26.835**, that last digit I wrote in bold is the last result, right? Because your echo doesn't print any delimiter, so it looks a large number. You should really put the `echo` outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: @Hamham PHP is smart enough to apply arithmetic operation to number that its data type is string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033340/how-to-find-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-a-table-in-sql-server-2005?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to start XDebug and step through the code to see what happens

Comment: @AmmarFaizi yes but this is not a good way. Using strict type is a good practice each PHP developper should do in their code. If you need to do some arithmetics, use float or integer, not string, however it runs with it. Strong type improve your code quality. And with the next PHP versions, PHP will be stricter on the strong type (for php 7.4 and +)..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the `echo` outside of the `while` loop, your current code is printing the accumulation of total variable in every single loop cycle, that is why the output weird.

```php
<tr>
   <th colspan="7">Total Vektor S</th>
      <td>
         <?php
            $totvs = 0;
            $sql2 = mysqli_query($koneksi,"select * from tb_alternatif");
            while ($hasil1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql2))
            {
               $vsc1 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[2],$nb1),3);
               $vsc2 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[3],-$nb2),3);
               $vsc3 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[4],$nb3),3);
               $vsc4 = number_format(pow((int)$hasil1[5],-$nb4),3);
               $totalvs = $vsc1 + $vsc2 + $vsc3 + $vsc4;
               $totvs += $totalvs;
            }
            echo $totvs;
       ?>
   </td>
</tr>
```