# Finding SUM of different columns in MySQL with different WHERE conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following table called `designerindices`

[image]

I want to do the sum and the pseudo code as below

`SUM(duration1) WHERE designer1 = X AND designerHistSrNumber = 16 +` 
`SUM(duration2) WHERE designer2 = X AND designerHistSrNumber = 16 +` 
`SUM(duration3) WHERE designer3 = X AND designerHistSrNumber = 16 +` 
`SUM(duration4) WHERE designer 4 = X AND designerHistSrNumber = 16`

To do that I wrote the following 4 separate queries

`SELECT SUM(duration1) as sumdur1 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer1 = "X"`
This should output 10

`SELECT SUM(duration2) as sumdur2 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer2 = "X"`
This should output 2.4

`SELECT SUM(duration3) as sumdur3 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer3 = "X"`
This should output 5

`SELECT SUM(duration4) as sumdur4 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer4 = "X"`
This should output 1.1

I have to execute the above queries 4 times. The finally add `sumdur1 + sumdur2 + sumdur3 + sumdur4`. The total should be 18.5

Is there any easy and direct way to do this instead of doing the above way?

Comment: This may answer your question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033340/how-to-find-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-a-table-in-sql-server-2005/11033391

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want here generally is called conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN designer1 = 'X' THEN duration1 ELSE 0 END) AS dur1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN designer2 = 'X' THEN duration2 ELSE 0 END) AS dur2,
    SUM(CASE WHEN designer3 = 'X' THEN duration3 ELSE 0 END) AS dur3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN designer4 = 'X' THEN duration4 ELSE 0 END) AS dur4
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    designerHistSrNumber = 16
```

Comment: seems like it is not doing SUM. When I run this query, it is just getting the first value of each duration column only. Eg: dur1 showing 10, dur2 showing 2.4, dur3 showing 5 and dur4 showing 1.1.

Comment: @Anu According to your sample data, there is only one record where `designer1`='X' and `designerHistSrNumber`=16. Same for the other SUMs: there is only one matching record for each of those conditions. That explains why `dur1` = 10, `dur2` = 2.4, etc.

Comment: @kmoser Sorry my bad. You are right. Your suggestion is correct.

Comment: @kmoser But is this way faster and efficient in finding sum compared to using multiple select cases suggested by another person for this question?

Comment: By the way do you know how can I get an overall sum? because now i need to add dur1 + dur2+ dur3 + dur4 to get overall sum. Instead is there a way to get it one shot?

Comment: Just add together the four `CASE` expressions in my answer.  If you find that too ugly, then you could subquery my answer and then just sum the aliases.

Comment: @Anu Unless your DB is enormous and/or poorly indexed, I suspect the performance differences between the two methods will be negligible. But don't take my word for it: perform some tests and let us know the results!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap all your 4 queries in seperate Select clause and have addition in that, like

```
Select (
(SELECT SUM(duration1) as sumdur1 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer1 = "X")
+
(SELECT SUM(duration2) as sumdur2 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer1 = "X")
+
(SELECT SUM(duration3) as sumdur3 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer1 = "X")
+
(SELECT SUM(duration4) as sumdur4 FROM designerindices WHERE designerHistSrNumber = 16 AND designer1 = "X")
) from Dual;
```

Comment: This works well too. But if use multiple select cases, will it be slow when comes to large tables?

Comment: @Anu The downside of this approach is that it requires _four_ separate full scans of the `designerindices` table, whereas using a single select with conditional aggregation only requires one scan.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just select the individual SUMS:

```
SELECT
  SUM(duration),
  SUM(duration2),
  SUM(duration3),
  SUM(duration4)
FROM
  designerindices
WHERE
  designerHistSrNumber=16 AND designer1="X"
```

This will sum the individual columns, but only for rows that match the `WHERE` clause. Since you want the same `WHERE` clause for each `SUM()`, you can just specify it once.

Comment: ...because the restriction isn't always on `designer1`, it is also on `designer2`, `designer3`, etc.

Comment: I was basing my query on OP's individual queries, all of which are dependent on `designer1`. So perhaps the original post needs to be clarified.

Comment: @kmoser Sorry that was a typo mistake from me. designer must vary for each query

Comment: I just corrected it

Comment: @kmoser Please read the above 2 OP comments, which confirm my initial comment under your answer.